# 7-ZIP How to extract a particular file present in a nested zipped file

Tags: windows-7, zip, 7-zip, 7za

I have a Zipped file which contains multiple Zipped file(logs of different servers). I have to extract a file(only one copy) named "diagnostics.xml" which is present in each of the zipped files.

I am using the below command. Tried multiple times but not sure for some reason, it is not working. Could you please suggest.

```
7z e "C:\users\Logs\test.zip" -oC:\users\Logs -ir!diagnostics.xml

**Folder Structure:**
test.zip(contains the below zipped files) 
  => Server1_Logs.zip(contains the diagnostics.xml)
  => Server2_Logs.zip(contains the diagnostics.xml)
  => Server3_Logs.zip(contains the diagnostics.xml)
```

Please note that we need to extract only one diagnostics.xml(from any server).

Comment: I doubt this is possible the way you want it. `7z` extracts an archive. That’s it. Nothing about nested archives or whatever. You’ll have to build that yourself, around the `7z` command.